# Получить список Queue и Exchanges в RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

Можно ли получить как-то список существующих очередей? Хочу в дальнейшем использовать их в c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот тут упоминают HTTP API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23483386/5752652) - попробовал на своей машине, работает. Читайте JSON, парсите при помощи Json.Net.

> http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges
>
> http://localhost:15672/api/queues